# What is the scientific term form something that 'wraps around' a shape

Tags: geometry, terminology

I was wondering if there is a mathematical term for this: 
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJIZw.png]

Imagine you had given the black shape - what does the red shape? I would call it, it wraps around the black one.

Actually I am looking for a way to calculate / compute this. But i thought if i knew the name i would have more luck to google it.

Sorry for this vague description - Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) ${{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}$

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea where I could find an insight on how to find a convex hull for a given set up points?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms and similar searches